# touch support on high level

Tags: java-me

is it possible active touch support on high level item`s(form , list , ... ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what your asking is if it is possible to use a touch screen with form's? the answer is yes if you use the basic elements and you only have a touch screen the phone will work out everything for you. However if you want your own GUI you'll have to use the pointerPressed(int x, int y), pointerReleased(int x, int y) and/or pointerDraged(int x, int y) methods.

Or if your asking about enabling a touch screen in your emulator you have to go to your devices' location in your file system (mine is at ~/.WTK/WTK2.5.2/wtklib/devices/DefaultColorPhone) and change the touch_screen line in the .properties file to "touch_screen=true"

hope this helps